# Just a short question abour rosdep installs

Tags: ros, catkin-package, rosdep-install

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

i got a short and I think easy for you to answer question about installing dependencies.

If I download a packages from source like turtlebot_simulator or something else, I usually run rosdep to install all my dependencies. And it works great.
But I am just wondering where ROS install the missing packages? They are not in my workspace afterwards but everything is working.

Ok I maybe was a little bit too fast with creating a question. I think I found the path:
/opt/ros//share/
But can I change the installation path somehow? Because you can't cut or copy something out of the /opt/ folder by hand

So how should I modify the code for my needs if I dont know where it is :) ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194661/just-a-short-question-abour-rosdep-installs/) by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 232 on 2014-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The standard distribution format for ROS packages on Ubuntu is binaries (debs), and the install into `/opt/ros/<distro>`. rosdep can find and install these for you, along with installing any normal ubuntu packages that might be required as dependencies.

**You cannot and should not attempt to modify the installed binary packages.**

If you want to modify a package or see how it works, you should go to the package's wiki page, download the source code to your workspace, and modify and build it there. Any package that you have installed in your workspace will override (shadow) a binary package with the same name, so you don't have to worry about uninstalling binary packages. (This process is call **overlaying**).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-10-10**:
So you mean if a packages will  be installed by rosdep and i want to mofidy it i shoudl download it seperatly to my workspace an do another catkin_make?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-10**:
Yes, that is correct.